# Error in dialog box creation

Tags: android

In my android app I am using following code to generate dialog box.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Message");
    TextView ok = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Close dialog
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

It gives proper dialog box. However, when I include `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >` in manifest file, the dialog box becomes much smaller in height and width. Why this is happening ? How to correct this without removing no-titlebar code from the manifest ?

Comment: Do you not want a title bar on your entire application or just on the dialog?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken i do not want title bar in entire application

Comment: What about putting <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" > to the manifest and don't worry about it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dialog that uses a theme other than the one specified in your manifest using this constructor:

`Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);`